# Proof of Vizing's Theorem (simple graph)

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, coloring

I have to understand the proof of the Vizing's theorem (page 161-163) from the link.
There are some steps in the proof of the lemma I don't understand:

1. Why is it $A(x) \subseteq T \, \forall x \in S$? If $T$ is the set of vertices from $Y$ which are reachable from u by $M$-alternating path in $H$ how can $A(x)$ which is sets of colours available at the neighbours of $v$ be a subset of $T$?
2. Why is $\tilde{A}(v) \subseteq Y \backslash T$, where $Y$ is the set of $k$ colours available to color the edges of $G$?
3. Why is it that $\sum_{x \in S} |A(x)|- |S\backslash u| > 2|T|-|T|$? I know that $|S\backslash u|=|T|$. Is it because we have assumed in the lemma that "[...] $G-v$ has a $k$-edge colouring with respect to which every neighbour of $v$ has at least two available colours, except possibly one vertex, which has at least one available color" that $\sum_{x \in S} |A(x)| > 2|T|$?

Beside from these questions can someone explain why the lemma "helps to proof" or proof
Vizing's theorem.
And it is written that "we prove the theorem by induction, assuming that there is a $(\Delta +1)$-edge colouring og $G-v$, where $v \in V$. To complete the proof, it suffices to show how a $(\Delta+1)$-edge colouring og $G$ itself can be obtained from $(\Delta+1)$-edge colouring of $G-v$". I'm new to induction proof and I don't understand what the base case is here.

[Proof of Vizing's theorem p. 161-163](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7E2014-15/1term/ma121a/Bondy%20-%20Short%20proofs.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I can explain the last questions: The induction is on the number of vertices in the graph. The base case can be a graph with one vertex (and hence zero edges), that clearly has a 0-edge colouring. Or, if you prefer, let the base case be a graph with two vertices and hence at most one edge. It has $\Delta \leq 1$ and has a 1-edge colouring, so Vizing holds. See also the remark below the lemma. The lemma provides the induction step in the induction.